# Delete remote git branch

Tags: git, github

I´ve tried several times to delete my remote ¨search¨ branch and I can´t seem to achieve it. It´s saying that remote ref does not exist.
Here is everything I´ve done:

```
angel@DESKTOP-20K232E MINGW64 ~/angelybello (web50/projects/2020/x/wiki)
$ git branch -a
* web50/projects/2020/x/wiki
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/web50/projects/2020/x/wiki
  remotes/origin/main
  remotes/origin/web50/projects/2020/x/search
  remotes/origin/web50/projects/2020/x/wiki

angel@DESKTOP-20K232E MINGW64 ~/angelybello (web50/projects/2020/x/wiki)
$ git branch -d remotes/origin/web50/projects/2020/x/search
error: branch 'remotes/origin/web50/projects/2020/x/search' not found.

angel@DESKTOP-20K232E MINGW64 ~/angelybello (web50/projects/2020/x/wiki)
$ git push origin --delete remotes/origin/web50/projects/2020/x/search
error: unable to delete 'remotes/origin/web50/projects/2020/x/search': remote ref does not exist
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/me50/angelybello.git'

angel@DESKTOP-20K232E MINGW64 ~/angelybello (web50/projects/2020/x/wiki)
$ git push origin -d remotes/origin/web50/projects/2020/x/search
error: unable to delete 'remotes/origin/web50/projects/2020/x/search': remote ref does not exist
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/me50/angelybello.git'

angel@DESKTOP-20K232E MINGW64 ~/angelybello (web50/projects/2020/x/wiki)
$ git push origin --delete web/50/projects/2020/x/search
error: unable to delete 'web/50/projects/2020/x/search': remote ref does not exist
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/me50/angelybello.git'
```

Comment: Your branch is called `web50/projects/2020/x/wiki`, not `web/50/projects/2020/x/wiki`. Your last command would be correct if not for the typo in the branch name

Comment: The easiest way is `git push some-remote :some-branch` (with the colon).

Comment: I fixed the typo in the last command and it says my branch is protected, I don´t understand what this means. remote: error: GH006: Protected branch update failed for refs/heads/web50/projects/2020/x/search.
remote: error: Cannot delete this protected branch
To https://github.com/me50/angelybello.git
 ! [remote rejected] web50/projects/2020/x/search (protected branch hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/me50/angelybello.git'

Comment: Unprotect your branch on GitHub, then delete it. https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/defining-the-mergeability-of-pull-requests/about-protected-branches